# [cassandra]cassandra dead but subsys locked error messgae

Tags: cassandra

I have a cassandra cluster with 5 nodes and 3 of the nodes are up and 2 are down. when i try to do

```
sudo service cassandra status
cassandra dead but subsys locked
```

My log files show that

```
ERROR 21:53:09 Exception encountered during startup
org.apache.cassandra.io.FSReadError: java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsDescriptor.readFromFile(HintsDescriptor.java:235) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsCatalog.load(HintsCatalog.java:65) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsService.<init>(HintsService.java:88) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsService.<clinit>(HintsService.java:63) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy.<clinit>(StorageProxy.java:124) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:561) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:548) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:385) [apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:601) [apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:730) [apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readInt(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsDescriptor.deserialize(HintsDescriptor.java:344) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsDescriptor.readFromFile(HintsDescriptor.java:231) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
```

System config:

```
uname -a 
Linux ip-10-100-52-37 4.9.20-11.31.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Apr 13 01:53:57 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Please suggest me how to resolve this.

Thanks !

Comment: Check this https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/204424739-Apache-Cassandra-fails-to-start-with-FSReadError-and-java-io-EOFException-

Comment: Thanks ! it worked:)